# To show value in the textfield in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, textfield

I am trying to create a page to edit profile and using the below text field, the user had already a set name which is retrieved from the firestore database and stored in a String variable, all I want is that when the user opens his profile page to edit `String value` should be shown in the `textfield` , I am not getting such option to do so.

please guide me

```
TextField( decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Sweetie',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: greyColor),
                        ),
                        controller: controllerNickname,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          nickname = value;
                        },
                        focusNode: focusNodeNickname,
                      )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `TextField` then you need to declare `TextEditingController` and set it as `controller` property of the `TextField` and set your text to

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: "Set My Text Here")
```

But you have to `dispose` it in the `dispose` method

Another options is

```
TextFormField(
   initialValue: "Set My Text Here",
)
```

You can use whaterver you want

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a controller you can set controllerNickname.text to your require value in your initstate method

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the value to controller :

```
String value = "Jhon"

controllerNickname.text = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a nickname value through the constructor of the profile page, and set the value of nickname as below where you required. Try to set this in `initState()` method

```
controllerNickname.text = 'XYZ';
```